# Delta Optimize Skips Optimization of Table

Tags: apache-spark, delta

I have a Delta table with >25GiB and exactly 200 files. The table is externally managed (ADLS Gen2). The table has a lot of columns, roughly 120 columns.

I only do merge operations on the table, and vacuum after every merge. The merge operation only happens once a day, and mimics a upsert operation for ingesting new data and updating old ones. Pretty standard stuff.

Now I also want to perform a optimize operation on the table, but whenever I do it finishes immediately. And I can see no optimize operation in the history of the table. I tried to perform the optimize manually in an SQL notebook and the result dataframe of the operation was:

```
{
  "numFilesAdded": 0,
  "numFilesRemoved": 0,
  "filesAdded": {
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "avg": 0,
    "totalFiles": 0,
    "totalSize": 0
  },
  "filesRemoved": {
    "min": null,
    "max": null,
    "avg": 0,
    "totalFiles": 0,
    "totalSize": 0
  },
  "partitionsOptimized": 0,
  "zOrderStats": null,
  "numBatches": 0,
  "totalConsideredFiles": 200,
  "totalFilesSkipped": 200,
  "preserveInsertionOrder": true
}
```

My question is why does the table skip being optimized? Is it because the high amount of columns?

Comment: You may need to tune some properties. See [this](https://books.japila.pl/delta-lake-internals/commands/optimize/#bin-packing)

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the documentation. However when I ran the optimize command with a Zorder column it did some work, but without Zordering nothing happens.